# How to activate overprovisioning on SanDisk SSD

Tags: ssd

I have SanDisk x210 SSD, I read that overprovisioning can increase durability, however I cannot find a way to activate it. Is it possible for SanDisk SSD to use some custom application and set it.

Answer (score 1):

Overprovisioning is an intrinsic property of the SSD. Since it involves hardware, it is not possible to "turn it on".

In some cases, a firmware update can provide a higher level of overprovisioning at the cost of available storage capacity - this involves losing all data on the drive and is supported on a very small selection of drive types, expecially not the x210

Comment: I wonder how they were able to performe test under this link http://www.tweaktown.com/reviews/5822/sandisk-x210-256gb-business-class-ssd-exploring-overprovisioning/index.html .

Comment: This test says exactly what I mentioned: The overprovisioning is intrinsic to the drive, it can't be "enabled" or "disabled" from the outside. Thank you for confirming this!